# Ubuntu : language support showing only french and english

Tags: language-support

I wanted to install the Japanese language on my ubuntu 16.04, but following some tutorials, I realized that it was not present in the language-support panel, in install/remove languages. In almost every discussion I have seen on this topic, people could choose a wide variety of languages, but I can only choose between French or English. The only person with the same problem magically solved it with a apt-get update, but it didn't work for me.
Here is a picture.

[Install/Remove language menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEHiy.png)

What can I do ?

My ultimate goal is to be able to type japanese like in windows (typing in romanji, which converts into kana and kanjis), and I found tutorials but it requires the support of the japanese language.

Thanks !

Comment: `sudo apt update` by itself solves nothing because it does nothing else than checking the repositories for newer versions of installed packages. Follow it by `sudo apt full-upgrade` and it may work because the second command is what downloads and installs the updates you need.

Comment: If what @MichaelBay suggested does not help, can you please start Language Support from terminal with the command `gnome-language-selector`. Then click the _Install / Remove Languages..._ button, and let us know any messages which show up in terminal. Copy the output and paste it into your question (by editing it).

Comment: I did the full-upgrade, and it didn't change anything. No message appears in terminal when I click the Install/Remove Languages button.

Comment: Do you have a working Internet connection?

Comment: Yes I do, it's perfectly working.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the not installed languages don't show up in that list.

But these are some steps to let you type Japanese anyway:

- Install Fcitx

  ```
  sudo apt install fcitx
  ```
- Install a Japanase input method engine

  ```
  sudo apt install fcitx-mozc
  ```
- Make Fcitx the input method framework

  ```
  im-config -n fcitx
  ```
- Reboot
- Go to *System Settings -> Text Entry* and add **Mozc** to the input sources

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
I think I may have a problem with my packages because i get an error message, saying that there is no version that can be installed. Mozc cannot be found either...

Comment: @Pietrovosky: If you need help to sort out that package issue, I'd suggest that you ask a new question, where you provide as much details as you can about the problem.

Comment: OK, I tried few things first, and magically... it worked, even though I don't know why.
I have downloaded the fcitx and fticx-mozc packages from a website and tried to install them. I got an error message concernings missing librairies, but they were recognized anyway, but still did not work. My package manager (I think) said that the packages were corrupted, and I needed to do `apt-get -f install`. I did that, which removed the two packages. Next thing, I launch the language support window, it proposes an update, and magically all languages appear now.
Thanks to everyone for their help !